# How to understand the Hearts of Iron III interface?

Tags: hearts-of-iron-3

I really enjoyed Europe Universalis III, and firstly thought of it as hard to understand -- until I saw HOI III and the following image. The horrendousness of the image is multiplied by 10 at least in the full game version.

[image: Screen 1]

So, is there some user-friendly guide into HOI III other than standard tutorials roughly consisting of the same screens? Because I really want to become a Nazi-world king as soon as possible.

Comment: Chaotic.one, you could have linked to the image :)

Comment: Ah, I wish the rules of question titles were less polite, and permitted emotion human factor.

Comment: That is one horrible interface.

Comment: Having tried the demo last week, I can sympathize. Granted, part of the problem is that there's a lot more to manage than there is in EU3, but it still seems needlessly complex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As with anything else, the HoI3 interface becomes easy to understand with practice. You soon learn to ignore anything you don't need. The scope of this game is such that you don't strictly need to use some parts to play (e.g. the Diplomacy screen) - the AI can manage that for you reasonably well.

Play though the built-in tutorials, then follow this guide from [start to finish](http://www.paradoxian.org/hoi3wiki/Your_first_game), and you'll learn it soon enough.